# rake db:migrate時のエラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

#### 前提・実現したいこと

エラーを解決し、migrateを行いたい。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

[このサイト](https://cyllabus.jp/courses/LVlXWNb8GcWTKy8x1gHS5g)の『2.会員登録機能　マイグレーションしてデータベース・テーブルを作成する』でrake db:migrateを行おうとしたところ、画像の様なメッセージが出てしまい実行できませんでした。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 該当のソースコード

メッセージに表記されてい
20170714075620_add_name_and_screen_name_and_bio_to_users.rbのソースコードは↓です

```
 class AddNameAndScreenNameAndBioToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :users, :name, :string
    add_column :users, :screen_name, :string
    add_column :users, :bio, :string
  end
end
```

#### 試したこと

```
rake db:reset
rake db:create
```

を用いてデータベースの作り直しは試してみました。

#### 補足情報(言語/FW/ツール等のバージョンなど

Rails 5.1.2
ruby 2.3.3p222(2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x64-mingw32]

Comment: リンク先のページでは `rails g sorcery:install` をしていますが、これはやりましたか?

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/84302

Answer (score 1):

usersテーブルがないと出ているので、

```
rails g scaffold user -s --no-stylesheets --skip-migration
```

を実行し忘れている可能性が高いか後に実行してしまっていると思われます。
rails destroyを利用してやり直すこともできますが、あまり慣れていないご様子なので、生成されたファイルを削除するか、最初からやり直すことをおすすめします。